# Erro com Bootstrap 4 no Angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Eu bati com o seguinte problema no Angular ao tentar instalar o Bootstrap em sua versão 4:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at browserslist (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\wamp64\www\angular\emag2\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:231:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 4:14-127
 @ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css ./src/styles.css
```

O que fzer para corrigir?

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre devido a um bug entre a versão do bootstrap que você está usando
e o CLI do Angular, já foi reportado aqui: [Bug boostrap >=4 e CLI Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020)

Uma forma de corrigir isso é mudando a versão do bootstrap dentro do seu arquivo package.json, eu por exemplo alterei a minha versão para "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
dei um npm install e depois um ng serve, funcionou normalmente, não sei qual a última versão funcional, porém essa 3 está me atendendo normalmente, cabe a você procura a última versão até o momento funcional com o CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui colocar o Bootstrap 4 a funcionar sem problemas no meu projeto em Angular 5. Não sei se resolve o seu problema mas estes foram os passos que segui para incorporar o Bootstrap no meu projeto:

1. Instalei o Bootstrap com o comando `npm install Bootstrap --save`;
2. Acrescentei a entrada
   `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` no vetor de
   `"styles"` no ficheiro `.angular-cli.json`;
3. Acrescentei a entrada
   `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"` no
   vetor de `"scripts"` no ficheiro `.angular-cli.json`;

Para acrescentar o Jquery usei o mesmo método, instalar via `npm` e acrescentar no ficheiro `angular-cli.json`.

---

Excerto das minhas entradas no `packages.json`:

```
(...)

  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1"

(...)
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",

(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Isso acontece porque existe um bug entre a nova versão do angular-cli e o mais novo bootstrap. Para corrigir o erro, você deverá:

1. Apagar o diretório node_modules
2. Retire a acentuação na frente da versão da aplicação no package.josn da linha que tem seu bootstrap instalado, deixando somente `"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2"`
3. Agora execute o comando `npm install`

Agora é só compilar e prontinho!